# IExplorer ERROR script 5009 with <form> is bug?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a piece of code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"/><title>t</title></head>
<body> 
<form id="F1">

    <script>
    function doit()
    {
        if(!F1.checkValidity())return;
        alert("ID="+FName.value); //Do some processing
    }
    </script>

    Enter your name:  <input ID="FName" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" required ><br />
    <p><button OnClick="doit()"> DO IT</button></p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It gets some input and validates it before processing data.  According to https://validator.w3.org/check it does conform with HTML5. And It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IExplorer 11. It says ERROR SCRIPT 5009 "FName is undefined".  However if I remove the **form** tag, FName becomes defined. But then I could not check the form validity.

I wonder if this is a IExplorer bug and how could I fix it. Thanks!

Comment: It is a bug, but a consistent approach to named properties of the window object (which is what you have) is a relatively recent HTML5 feature, so it's unsurprising that browser implementations are still catching up. There are other ways of dealing with it, such as using `document.getElementById('FName')` but @Robert's solution seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

The input is a child of the form rather than the document.

I was able to duplicate the problem in IE.  I solved it by referencing the element as F1.FName, i.e., as a child of the form element.  And this worked in IE, Chrome, and Firefox. I suppose this is the expected behavior rather than a problem, but was unable to find a supporting reference.

```
if(!F1.checkValidity())return;
alert("ID="+F1.FName.value); //Do some processing
```